# Indicate angle in QTableView - possible approaches

Tags: c++, qt, svg, qpainter

I want to indicate an angle (0-359degrees) in a `QTableView` column as an arrow pointing in that very direction and wonder what would be the best approach:

1. Should I use a `QPixmap` and rotate the image accordingly?
2. Should I use the [SVG approach](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtsvg-svggenerator-example.html) and draw the image as SVG, then display it as `QPixmap`?
3. Should I draw that column directly with `QPainter` ([docu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainter.html))?
4. Anything completely different?

The approach has be reasonable fast, as the table view might contain 1-250 rows, and then I would have to draw as many angle icons. As 1 degree can hardly be distinguished I was thinking of creating 120 icons (as per 3 degrees) in memory and then just fetch the closest one.

Comment: I think every approach will work. Qt will only draw items that had to be redrawn, so it will never have to draw all 250 items. But even 250 items is not large amount of work